# How to validate response it its not blank

Tags: api, automation, karate

I have to verify the response if it's not blank

```
Feature: Test Feature
Scenario: Test scenario
    Given url baseUrl 
    And path TariffsApiPath = '/api/test/ServiceAdd
    When method get
    Then status 200
    * if (response != [] || '') karate.call('/features/PASE/helper/ServiceAddressessHelper.feature@BaseScenarioServiceAddressess5')
```

I am trying to achieve the same with this code. But I am not able to figure out how to pass

This is ServiceAddressessHelper.feature file

```
Feature: Helper Feature
  
   @BaseScenarioServiceAddressess5
   Scenario: Helper scenario
   * match each response == expectedResponseServiceAddressess
```

Comment: please spend some time reading the docs and examples, you have yet to understand some fundamentals